# How to use non native cordova plugins in ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use this plugin in my Ionic 4 app:
https://github.com/IOCare/cordova-plugin-smartconfig

I installed plugin using `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/IOCare/cordova-plugin-smartconfig.git` and it seems to be added to project fine. Cordova plugin list shows: cordova-plugin-smartconfig 1.0.4 "Cordova Smart Config"

**I have tried:**

`declare var espSmartConfig: any;` and using `espSmartConfig.startConfig()`

*and*

`declare var cordova: any;` and using `cordova.plugins.espSmartConfig.startConfig()`,

*and*

`declare var window: any;` and using `window.espSmartConfig.startConfig()`

..but everything is unidentified. I have tried with Ionic DevApp on my android phone and with chrome on my PC.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what. All documents I've found are referring to native plugins.

Comment: `I have tried with Ionic DevApp on my android phone and with chrome on my PC`. Ionic Dev app is a pre-built application that only contains a select set of Ionic Native plugins - you cannot install 3rd party plugins into it. Chrome is a browser and that plugin only supports native Android & iOS platforms. To use it you'll have to build your own native Android app using Cordova - [see here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As couple of you guys suggested I tried to build the App and run that on my phone. Worked like a charm with:

```
declare var espSmartConfig: any;
```

So the problem here was only my tools that I used to test the app.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: for my case, this thing is working in android but no in ios, I am using custom plugin added locally from my mac

Comment: @Joonas Lindström When you do espSmartconfig.startConfig, are those SSID, BSID. etc, of the router (aka real wifi) or of the esp32 card (aka access point wifi)?

Comment: @Joonas Lindstrom - Does this work on the Android simulator or do I need a real Android device?  Also, is there a way for the mobile device to get the SSID of the network it is connected to (like the ESPTouch app does) or will the user have to specify the SSID of the network manually with this plug in?

Answer (score 1):

1. First add the plugin using.

*cordova plugin add https://github.com/IOCare/cordova-plugin-smartconfig.git*

2. Then in app.ts

*declare var espSmartconfig;*

3. To start the config use this.

*espSmartconfig.startConfig("ssid", "00:00:00:00","password", "NO", 1, function (res) { }, function (error) {console.log(error);});*

4. Remember to stop the config once done.

*espSmartconfig.stopConfig(function (res) { console.log(res); }, function (error) {console.log(error);});*

Comment: It sounds like Joonas has already tried most of that, and is getting undefined values at `espSmartconfig.startConfig()`.

Comment: Joonas you should try this on actual mobile phone. Just upload the code and try that. I am using 

setTimeout(() => {
espSmartconfig.stopConfig(function (res) { console.log(res); }, function (error) {console.log(error);});
    }, 5000);

for stopping the smartconfig. The smartconfig must be stopped after every use. I stop it after 5 seconds so that the config is done and then it is stopped. Hope this helps

Comment: is `app.ts` the same as `main.ts`?